# Extjs: Load text to popup on button click with getComponent(''); as reference

Tags: extjs

I can only create new javascript, I don't have access to source code. A button & on click of that a popup is already there.

Now I want to write ext.js script to add text(HTML) on popup form.

[image: this]

---

[image]

---

I want text like below:

[image]

Below is the code I added in the console and I got the result as expected.

```
getComponent('addStakeholderUserBtn').on('click', function() {
    var addlabel = getComponent('stakeholderAddUserWindow');
    var labeltext = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    html: "Before adding a new user,'Add Existing Stakeholder'",
    bodyPadding: 10 
    });
    addlabel.insert(1,labeltext);
)};
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. It seems as though you already have a solution?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli open the images and check, on click of the button new component is created I want to add text to that component, but I can't do with editing the Ext.create(Button) since its restricted to edit source code. so how to add an event handler, listener to the existing button with Extjs

Comment: I assume that you can alter the javascript in the page right? Just put: Ext.onReady(function(){     //Exactly the code above     });